# How do I get SQL to append columns to the result set instead of adding more rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have 3 tables, they are `Events`, `SignOffs` and `Users`.

`Events` has the fields `EventId` (PK, int, autoincrement) and `EventTitle` (nvarchar(50)).

`SignOffs` has the fields `SignOffId` (PK, int, autoincrement), `EventId` (FK to `Events.EventId`) and SignedOffByUserId (FK to `Users.UserId`).

`Users` has the fields `UserId` (PK, int, autoincrement) and `UserName` (nvarchar(50)).

I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT [Events].EventId, EventTitle, UserName
FROM [Events]
     INNER JOIN [SignOffs] ON [Events].EventId = [SignOffs].EventId
     INNER JOIN [Users] ON [SignOffs].SignedOffByUserId = [Users].UserId
```

The problem with the above is you get a row for each person that signed off, so a given event can be repeated in the list multiple times if multiple people signed off.

What I want is for columns to be added to the result set for each person that signed off on an event. So the result set should look like this for an event where 3 people signed off:

`EventId` - `EventTitle` - `SignedOffByUser1` - `SignedOffByUser2` - `SignedOffByUser3`

I don't have any ideas about how this can be done and I'm not even sure how to articulate the problem succinctly to be able to search for answers.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server pivot".

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the data, this can either be done using the PIVOT operator.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

or you can use multiple case statements to achieve the same effect.

the limitations of both approaches is that you may only have a predefined number of columns. so if you have more than 3 signoffs for example you will not see them.

Another possiblity could be to put them into a csv list this would enable you to see them all on a single row no matter how many there are.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
(SELECT ',' + s.Name
FROM HumanResources.Shift s
ORDER BY s.Name
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000) AS CSV
```

this can be done in a sub query.

Hope this helps.